# Salient Object Detection Evaluation Data and Test Sets

Tags: data-request, images

I'm working on salient object detection and for evaluation of my proposed method I should compare it with other methods and models (as all do!). I just found that it isn't necessary to test every single method on several data sets. It seems that some of the top researchers in the field established a [Website](http://Salient%20Object%20Detection%20Evaluation%20Data%20and%20Test%20Sets) (Salient Object Detection Leaderboard) and made those [data](https://mmcheng.net/salobjbenchmark/) publicly available. However, there is an important problem here. The data are uploaded in [**pan.baidu**](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1dEaQqlF#list/path=%2Fsharelink524706114-884877716839535%2FShare&parentPath=%2Fsharelink524706114-884877716839535) and we cannot download it from outside of the China. Any solution for that?

Comment: From the section titled "Salient object detection datasets" on https://mmcheng.net/salobjbenchmark/, I am able to navigate to and download several of the benchmark datasets used in the paper.  I'm outside of China.

Comment: @sboysel, I didn't mean datasets. The data which is uploaded in Pan.Baidu. However, thanks to god, I found a friend in China and he provided me with the files. :)

Comment: Ah, I see how I misunderstood.  Glad you found a work around.